# VBA Word and using Excel columns as a lookup and replace

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a MS Word Doc that has the wrong words in it when it comes to me.  I have a list of these words in Excel column A of book1, sheet1.  I also have what the words should be column B of book1, sheet1.

The list is about 300 words but the doc is only 50 words.

My thought is to copy and paste the text in the word doc with the VBA.  Run a VBA to set Col A as a string and search the word doc.  When found, replace it with Col B.  At the end of the Doc set the next Col A as the string and do it again... until last line.

I've work in Excel coding but I lost on this one.  As always any help is great.

Robert

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [vba dictionary object](http://www.techbookreport.com/tutorials/vba_dictionary.html) to build a `dict` with your Excel values.

Then, you can parse every value of your dictionary and Search & Replace the value in your Word document. Need to test because it could be slow though.

Regards,